# Git 2.13 not working on Windows XP

Tags: git

I downloaded Git-2.13.0.32-bit setup.On executing,it shows an error Windows Vista or later needed.I have WIndows XP.What shall I do?Which alternative software shall I download?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDGki.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1153883/git-for-windows-xp

Comment: If I read the answer correctly, then Git `1.7.4` or earlier should be compatible with XP.

Comment: "Which alternative software shall I download", at the risk of preaching to the choir, you should install Windows 10 (or Windows 8). Not to get git working, that would just be icing on the cake, but to get to a secure operating system again.

Answer (score 3):

According to this page: [Git for Windows Prerequisites](https://git-for-windows.github.io/requirements.html), the last version of Git that supported Windows XP was 2.10.0.

You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.10.0.windows.1).

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.20 (Q4 2018, 18 months later), the documentation now clearly states:

> The minimum version of Windows supported by Windows port for Git is now set to Vista.

See [commit 2939a1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2939a1f70357d5b55232c2bf51e5ac32a4e7336c), [commit 3571e78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3571e78aa490e9e2d5cf12372ae042c782b27b53), [commit d7e357f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7e357fb9c702979d5b3a7d9faa869844a12e4d9) (03 Oct 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 29cce95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29cce957a7e58ed016e6699f069c713a2f188660), 16 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `mingw`: bump the minimum Windows version to Vista
>
> Quite some time ago, a last plea to the XP users out there who want to see Windows XP support in Git for Windows, asking them to get engaged and help, vanished into the depths of the universe.
>
> We tried for a long time to play nice with the last remaining XP users who somehow manage to build Git from source, but a recent update of mingw-w64 (7.0.0.5233.e0c09544 -> 7.0.0.5245.edf66197) finally dropped the last sign of XP support, and Git for Windows' SDK is no longer able to build core Git's `master` branch as a consequence. (Git for Windows' `master` branch already bumped the minimum Windows version to Vista a
>   while ago, so it is fine.)
>
> It is time to require Windows Vista or later to build Git from source.
>   This, incidentally, lets us use quite a few nice new APIs.